# Set cookie value before view loaded in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

I need to set a cookie value before my view called. otherwise I have to refresh the page to get cookie value in the view. The problem here is the value of cookie will get in controller.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Abstract/{meetingCode}")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Index(string meetingCode)
{
 var meetingAbstract = new MeetingAbstract();
 meetingAbstract.Meeting = _abstractContext.GetMeetingWithMeetingCode(meetingCode);
 if (meetingAbstract.Meeting != null)
 {
   var cookie = new HttpCookie("_culture");
   cookie.Value = meetingAbstract.Meeting.language.language_locale_code;//"en-US"; 
   cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365);
   cookie.Path = "/";
   this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
...
```

Any other way without refresh the page again to set cookie value?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies have some peculiar behaviour, I mean you create them in the Response stream, to be sent to the client, but they are not available in the Request stream until they are sent from the client.

I mean, you cannot access the cookie unless it is being sent from the client.

Anyway, why you need to refresh your page to access the cookie you just created? Is not easier to use the same variable?

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Abstract/{meetingCode}")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Index(string meetingCode)
{
 var meetingAbstract = new MeetingAbstract();
 meetingAbstract.Meeting = _abstractContext.GetMeetingWithMeetingCode(meetingCode);
 var cookie;
 if (meetingAbstract.Meeting != null)
 {
   cookie = new HttpCookie("_culture");
   cookie.Value = meetingAbstract.Meeting.language.language_locale_code;//"en-US"; 
   cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365);
   cookie.Path = "/";
   this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
 } else {
    cookie = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["_culture"];
 }
...
```